# Godelian problems with logic puzzles

Tags: logic, puzzle, provability

It occurs to me that the sort of reasoning common in many logic puzzles (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hat_puzzle or https://xkcd.com/blue_eyes.html), the persons involved all trust one another to behave perfectly rationally, and will make all possible sound deductions. If we assume that they all believe in axioms at least as strong as Peano Arithmetic (which is quite a reasonable assumption, I think), then it seems that this scenario is actually rather self-defeating via Godelian results, in particular [Lob's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6b%27s_theorem). In other words, a person can reason in the following degenerate manner in a hat puzzle:

Both I (A) and the person next to me (B) have common knowledge that we are perfectly rational and correct reasoners. B accepts me as a rational and correct, so he will accept the statement, "If A can prove that 1+1=3, then A will conclude this statement, and I trust A as rational and correct, so 1+1=3." I trust B to reason rationally and correctly, so he will conclude this statement, and because I accept any statement that B accepts, I accept that if I can prove 1+1=3, then 1+1=3. By [Lob's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6b%27s_theorem), 1+1=3.

The reasoning I'm making here is quite informal, so I'm not sure if I've made a subtle mistake, but I don't see any easy way around Godelian issues here. In order for the solutions to work, the people involved need to assume the others can perform reasoning about the natural numbers including induction, need to believe that others will prove anything that is provable, and need to believe that others will always come to sound conclusions. Is there any way we can recover the solutions to this sort of puzzle without allowing degenerate "solutions" like the above? In other words, can the assumptions about common knowledge and rationality here be formulated in a way that is provably consistent, while still allowing the commonly accepted solutions to these puzzles?

Comment: I don't understand the quoted statement yet. Is "this statement" meant to be self referential?

Comment: @CarlMummert; I think the point being made is that $A$ trusts $B$ to instantly derive all logical consequences (but no non-consequences) of his knowledge to any time, and this knowledge includes the fact that $A$ can instantly derive all logical consequences of _his_ knowledge, which includes the same fact about $B$, _ad infinitum_. But this means $A$ indirectly knows that _his own_ reasoning is consistent -- which seems to conflict with the second incompleteness theorem, and least if $A$'s reasoning is an axiomatic system. But if it is not, then how can we assume $B$ is able to model it?

Comment: Good question, +1. It looks like a promising way of attacking epistemic paradoxes such as the Unexpected Hanging.

Comment: Two quick answers suggest themselves: (1) Informal mathematical reasoning is inconsistent - which is already suggested by all the other paradoxes; alternatively (2) Löb's theorem does not apply to informal mathematical reasoning, because in informal mathematics we assume $\text{Pr}(\phi) \to \phi$ for every statement $\phi$, even false ones.  I am worried about whether this is really a "mathematical" question, though, if it comes down to choosing between alternatives like those.

Comment: In particular, I am not sure why we need two people in the example. If I accept Löb's theorem for informal provability, I can prove anything, as follows: "Given $\phi$, I know that if I can prove $\phi$ then $\phi$ holds. So, by Löb's theorem, $\phi$ holds."